# How to retrieve a sub collection with ngx-labs/firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, state-management, ngxs

In my projects, I've some collection of data that are related only to the logged user.
So the path to those items is `/users/{userId}/checkins`. It will be easy to set a security rule in firebase, and I think it will be quite efficient since I never need the checkin of other people.

How can I specify this in the `NgxsFirestore` implementation?

I currently have this:

```
import { Checkin } from './checkins.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxsFirestore } from '@ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CheckinsFirestore extends NgxsFirestore<Checkin> {
  protected path = 'users/{userId}/checkins/2021';
  idField = 'checkinId'
}
```

I guess I could inject `AngularFireAuth`, and register to the authState to compute this path, but since it's a property, it will probably be too late.

Thank you for your guidance.